# how can I plot 2 sets of contour in one single plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting two sets of contour as follows:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

plt.contourf(data_density[:,:,72], origin = 'upper', extent = (0,4.81,5,0), 
    levels=[0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9,4]) 

plt.colorbar()


plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

plt.contourf(data_density[:,:,theta_index], origin = 'upper', extent = (0,4.81,5,0),
    levels=[0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9,4])

plt.colorbar()
```

I would like to have the two plots together in one single plot (one next to the other), but I haven't been able to do it

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your figure to a variable:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
```

And then create a grid:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid
grid = AxesGrid(fig, 141, # similar to subplot(141)
                nrows_ncols = (1, 2),
                axes_pad = 0.05,
                label_mode = "1",
                )

left = grid[0]
right = grid[1]

# create a contourf on each grid element
left.contourf(data_density[:,:,72], origin = 'upper', extent ... ) 
right.contourf(data_density[:,:,theta_index], orig ...)
```

Alternatively you can use [subplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot).

Comment: Hi Oz123, I have tried to do that, but it's not exactly what I wanted. I'd like to have the two plots sticked together, not just side by side. Do you know how to do it? Thank you anyways for your help

Comment: you can control the spacing between two subplots, such that they are stuck together.

Comment: Alright, I did that. Now, I am not able to plot the colorbar next to the contour. It just shows a white bar when i write 'cbar_mode=single'